# How to do a full outer join with pandas dataframes with date condition?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to do a full outer join in pandas with one of the conditions being a date match. The SQL code would be like the following:

```
SELECT *
    FROM applications apps
    FULL OUTER JOIN order_data orders on apps.account = orders.account_order
                                    and  orders.[Order date] <=   apps.time_stamp;
```

How could I achieve this considering apps and order_data are two pandas dataframes?

I tried using pysql but full outer joins are not supported.

Thank you

Comment: I don't get why is this duplicate, the answer @coldspeed pointed me to doesn't explain the date <= filter

Comment: Sorry, the post has been reopened. But FYI, inequality based clauses are not supported, joining can only be done where column values are equal. You will need an additional `query` or boolean indexing step to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Pandas .join method lets you use outer joins: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html

Simply load up your two data frames and

```
a.join(b, how='outer')
```

will do it.

Comment: How do I specify the date filer in the join?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think you can—joins in pandas only operate on values that are equal to each other. You'll have to apply your date filter "after the fact"; do the JOIN first, and then knock out any rows that won't match.

Comment: But that will knock out rows and then I won't have a full outer join, right?

Comment: Are `account` and `account_order` unique on their respective tables?

Comment: No, each table has a unique ID (account_id and order_id), but the account and account_order can be repeated

Comment: I think it's going to be rough trying to do this in Pandas. You're probably better off either just writing some custom Python code or using a database that supports what you want to do.